# Getting this error after switching Wordpress site to WPEngine: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpengine

Migrated Wordpress site from Flywheel to WPEngine... A JS application I built is not working now and throwing this error - wondering if anyone knew or had any solutions.

Error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Page: https://oacaa.org/self-sufficiency-calculator/

Comment: For what it's worth, WPEngine has good customer support.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I had compressed the JS file thinking it would help it load better. After the migration is stopped working and started throwing errors. After having WPEngine support look throughout it and not be able to find the cause, I tried deleting the compressed JS and just adding the full file and it works now throwing no errors... If anyone else finds this problem and can't figure out a solution, maybe this will help lol. Not super exciting, but not the firsts thing I tried.